Undefined symbols in libvosk.so
I am trying to install vosk on Jetson Nano Developer kit.
After I followed the steps in https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install, I got the below error when I am trying to run a example program in Python.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_vosk.py", line 2, in <module>
    from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vosk/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    _c = open_dll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vosk/__init__.py", line 31, in open_dll
    return _ffi.dlopen(os.path.join(dlldir, "libvosk.so"))
OSError: cannot load library '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vosk/libvosk.so': /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vosk/libvosk.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So, I copied the prebuilt binary of libvosk.so from the releases tab of https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/releases from v0.3.45 aarch64.zip file.
Now the above error is resolved, but I am getting the below error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_vosk.py", line 2, in <module>
    from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vosk/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    _c = open_dll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vosk/__init__.py", line 31, in open_dll
    return _ffi.dlopen(os.path.join(dlldir, "libvosk.so"))
OSError: cannot load library '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vosk/libvosk.so': /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vosk/libvosk.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev

Can someone please help me to resolve this error.
I am expecting a solution for the above described problem
